# Virtual Keyboard in iOS Chrome browser sometimes covers content instead of pushing the viewport up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, google-chrome

I've run into a glitch in chrome on iOS where "scrolling" the screen down after an input focus causes the keyboard to obscure the bottom part of the page and a user cannot scroll down to see the elements below (this is where I have a textarea). This happens only in the iOS Chrome browser, not safari.

I'm going to walk through the steps to try and make this as clear as possible.

- A user focuses the textarea input. The behavior is as expected here: the keyboard pushes the screen up.
- If the user doesn't scroll at all and taps out of the input then this behavior will continue the next time they focus in the textarea (keyboard pushes the entire screen up).
- If the users drags the screen down to scroll up while the textarea is focused (no matter how little they "scroll") the screen has a snap-like effect and the keyboard covers the bottom of the content. This keyboard behavior is preserved...
- the keyboard continues to cover the content this way each time the user taps in and out of the textarea.
- The only way I have found to reset this effect is to pull the screen up when the textarea is not focused. This causes a little flicker effect and when the user clicks into the textarea the keyboard goes back to

I have "scrolling" in quotes because there is no actual scroll happening on the page as the height, body, and form are all 100% the height of the browser. The virtual keyboard really just pushes the viewport off the screen in the first scenario.

I made a video of the issue here: https://youtu.be/yD0tjMfy5I8

I can't find any information about why this is happening and I've not had any luck trying to style the form differently because (from what I can tell) there is no way to find the height of the visible area when the keyboard is opened (window.innerHeight doesn't work)

Has anyone found a way around this glitch?

Comment: Not a Chrome Apps question.

Comment: I am having the same issue with my website. The keyboard covers the content. It used to resize the viewport, like on all other browsers, before the update.

Comment: Are you using any particular framework (bootstrap, for instance) that might add some weird viewport behaviour behind the scene?